# How to change a text field to a date field in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql

I am writing a report using SQL Report Builder. I had to export two date related fields from a text field (customer_order_line_hist, field=message_text) using the following statement.

The original message_text field is always the same with the exception of the date information: “The planned delivery date has been changed from 2013-06-28 00.00.00 to 2013-05-16 00.00.00”

I am trying to convert the two output fields (FROM_DATE & TO_DATE) to either a datetime field or to the format mm/dd/yyyy.

I tried the CONVERT and CAST function without success.  Any ideas?

---

```
Select  SUBSTR(t.message_text, 49, 10) AS FROM_DATE,
        SUBSTR(t.message_text, 72, 10) AS TO_DATE,
        t.order_no,
        t.line_no,
        t.rel_no,
        t.line_item_no,
        t.history_no
FROM    customer_order_line_hist t
Where   t.message_text Like 'The planned delivery date%'
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, etc

Answer (score 0):

Convert should work if your syntax is correct.  Try this simplified test:

```
 declare @sText varchar(max)

 select @sText = 'The planned delivery date has been changed from 2013-06-28 00.00.00 to       2013-05-16 00.00.00'


 select  convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(@sText, 49, 10)) AS FROM_DATE,
    convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(@sText, 72, 10)) AS TO_DATE
```

Comment: My database is actually Oracle and I am using PL/SQL Developer to test my select statement.  I am getting the following error message when running the simplified test you suggested.

Comment: ORA-06550: line 1, column 9;
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following

begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
<a double-quoted-identifier> current cursor delete
exists prior

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0
CORE 11.2.0.3.0
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.  I figured it out on my own using the "TO_DATE" function.

Comment: Great news. Happy coding.