# T-SQL: Extract Substring

Tags: t-sql

I have to read dates from a varchar column with the following possible patterns ( month/day/year ):

```
1/1/2005 
1/13/2005 
10/9/2005 
10/13/2005
```

What is the correct way to read the day part of those dates with T-SQL?

Comment: Text file? and you want to process it in TSQL?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it is irrelevant, anyway i edited the question to avoid confucion.

Comment: Converting dates stored as text to a database date type has been widely explored.  For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317650/how-to-change-a-text-field-to-a-date-field-in-sql-select-statement.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades, not the same thing, look to my examples, i have to dig in the string to get only the day.

Comment: Yep.  So cast it to a date and use `DAY()`.  If you really want to use `SUBSTRING()` for some reason, please specify.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades you are right.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades, i get erros converting to date types:The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting to date and using day() would be the correct approach imo:

```
declare @t table (string varchar(10))
insert @t values ('1/1/2005'),('1/13/2005'),('10/9/2005'),('10/13/2005')
select day(cast(string as date)) as the_day from @t
```

Would give:

```
the_day
-----------
1
13
9
13
```

An alternative if you want to avoid casting would be to use the`substring`and`charindex`functions:

```
select 
    substring(
      string, 
      charindex('/', string)+1, 
      charindex('/', string, charindex('/', string)+1)-charindex('/', string)-1
    ) 
from @t
```

Comment: You can avoid the last cast: 
select day(string) as the_day from @t

Comment: @DavidGriffiths Good point, didn't think that day() operated on anything else than date[time] variables, but thanks to you I now know it can take string literals too. Nice to learn something new :)

Comment: I get: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @Elio.Batista I'm guessing the date got interpreted as dmy. How the date is interpreted is affected by your language setting. You might have to force it by using `set dateformat mdy`first.

Comment: Yes, that is why i wanted to avoid casting to date types, just read the single value from day part.

Comment: I tried forcing to read in US format: CONVERT (datetime, [BirthDate], 101) and i got the same error.

Comment: @Elio.Batista I updated my answer with a different way of doing it.

Comment: Just what i was after